# I'm trying to run expo project

Tags: react-native

Failed to Compile:

> /home/admin1/MERN/dheya/react-native-crud/node_modules/static-container/StaticContainer.js
> 5:21 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:21) You may need an
> appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are
> configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```js
export default class extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        shouldUpdate: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't have webpack.config.js

Comment: Only have babel.config.js

Comment: did you resolve it? i have the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

edit your `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...//other configs
    "web": {
      "build": {
        "babel": {
          "include": ["static-container"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then run this before you start the project again,

`npm uninstall webpack && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`